# Multiple tables or single table with multiple types?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-design

I am making a database with, for example, collections of `vehicles`. Some are `cars`, some are trucks. So I have a table like this:

```
COLLECTIONS: id, title, description
```

And then I have more table(s) with the lists of vehicles in each collection.

I could use multiple tables like this:

```
COLLECTION_CARS: collection_id, make, model, year

COLLECTION_TRUCKS: collection_id, make, model, year
```

Or I could have just a single table with a type field like this:

```
COLLECTION_VEHICLES: collection_id, vehicle_type, make, model, year. (And then just make the `vehicle_type` be `Car or Truck`)
```

Which is better, mainly with regards to performance?

Comment: Very similar vehicles, I'd consider one table for both types.

Comment: `vehicle_type ENUM('Car', 'Truck')`

Comment: What jarlh said and adding a lookup table that contains typeID and type that connets to it

Comment: @sagi, I was thinking of handling that in the php code, and just leaving mystery integers for type in the database.

Answer (score 3):

Although it is not possible to estimate the performance before seeing the queries that you intend to run, here are some general considerations that you could apply:

- If the total number of rows in `COLLECTION_CARS` and `COLLECTION_TRUCKS` is small (say, under a million), the approach will unlikely make a difference from the performance standpoint
- If the number of rows is large, and you often query trucks separately from cars or vice verse, using separate tables may be of an advantage
- If you always query cars and trucks, using a single table may provide a slight advantage

Performance aside, a single table gives you a more flexible design, because adding new types of vehicles (say, RVs) does not change the structure of your database. This applies to queries as well: imagine adding a third table for `COLLECTION_RV`, and changing all `SELECT`s that join to `COLLECTION_CARS` and `COLLECTION_TRUCKS` so that they join to `COLLECTION_RV`.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just make one table with an additional column? That would be best for SQL performance if you are worried about that.

```
COLLECTIONS: id, title, description, type, make, model, year
```

[image]

[image]

Simply open a new query in SQL server and run this code to generate the new table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[collections](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [title] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [description] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [type] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [model] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [make] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [year] [numeric](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: But then where is the make model and year stored?

Comment: Simply add all the fields that you want into one table and you will be fine. Make your id number an auto increment (Identity Seed)

Comment: But then I would have data like this:
"Fastest Cars", "List of fastest cars", Ford Mustang 2001
"Fastest Cars", "List of fastest cars", Dodge Charger 2003
"Fastest Cars", "List of fastest cars", Porche 911 2006
"My favorite trucks", "These are my fav trucks", Chevy Colorado 2011
"My favorite trucks", "These are my fav trucks", Ford Escape 2009

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? That is where you use a SQL view or stored procedure or even a SSRS report to filter out what you want. For example, SELECT     id, title, description, type, model, make, year
FROM         dbo.collections
WHERE     (type = 'Truck') AND (model = 'Ford')

Comment: What I am trying to do with it, is have a bunch of collections of vehicles. I'm saying that If I were to store the vehicle information with the collection information, then I would be storing the titles of the collections many many times with each vehicle in each collection, which can't be a good way to do it.

Comment: Then the table structure and example I have given will work correctly, you will need to use a SQL view or SSRS report to change your variables such as model or type. In your view or SSRS report you can change the values as needed including DESC or ASEC order.

Comment: The other way to do this is to create two tables, one with a primary key and the second with a foreign key. That way you can point the collection with the key and when you create the SQL view you can simply join the two tables based on the key, otherwise one table will work using the groupby function in a SQL view.

Comment: Your example would 'work', but it would have me storing the titles and descriptions of each collection N times where N = the number of vehicles in each collection. Then if you want to change the name of a collection you would have to change every instance of it. You aren't supposed to do that in databases right?